# make the character follow the image route in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm now working on a 2D game, but I have a problem in here. I want to make a character follow the route that I made smoothly, but the character just want to follow one image. Well, this is going to hard to explain, so this is the image of it :

[image]

In that picture, I want to make the character follow that white route one by one, but the character just want to go one of the route. I put that white route in the array like this :

```
public Image[] route;
```

and for the the position, I made two vector2 where there is a start position and the end position :

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject character;

public Image[] question;

private Vector2 startpos;
private Vector2 endpos;

private float timelerp = 2f;
private float currentlerptime = 0;

void Start()
{
    //another code
    startpos = character.transform.position;
}

void Update()
{
    if(question[0] == true)
    {
        for(int I=0; I>5; I++)
        {
            endpos = route[I].transform.position;
            calculate();
            character.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(startpos, endpos,calculate());
        }
    }

//another code;
}

private float calculate()
{
    currentlerptime += Time.deltaTime;
    if (currentlerptime >= timelerp)
    {
        currentlerptime = timelerp;
    }

    return currentlerptime / timelerp;
}
```

Comment: `for(int I = 0; I > 5; I++)` your for loop will never run.

Comment: Questions about game AI or game programming in general may get more favorable responses on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/  Hope this helps. :)